# JSON data, cant load console error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

so, i create Json data as question.json
Json:

```
"Endokrynologia"[
    {   "title":"Endokrynologia",
        "id": "001",
        "date":"08J", 
        "question":"Niedoczynność przedniego płata przysadki u dorosłych mężczyzn nie powoduje:",
        "answear01": "zmniejszenia wydzielania TSH.",
        "answear02": "zmniejszenia wydzielania aldosteronu.",
        "answear03": "niepłodności.",
        "answear04": "zmniejszenia wydzielania kortyzolu.",
        "answear05": "niedoczynności tarczycy." }, 
        {
        "id": "002",
        "date":"11W", 
        "question":"30-letnia kobieta o dziecięcej budowie twarzy i zimnej suchej skórze, nie miesiączkuje. Stwierdzenie niskiego stężenia FSH, TSH i prolaktyny wskazuje na:",
        "answear01": "ciążę.",
        "answear02": "zespół przedwczesnego wygasania czynności jajników.",
        "answear03": "wszystkie prawdziwe.",
        "answear04": "nadczynność tarczycy.",
        "answear05": "niedoczynność przysadki mózgowej." }
]
```

and a call function with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.getJSON('question.json', function(data) {
    //do stuff with your data here
});
});
```

but i get console error like:

> Failed to load
>   file:///C:/Users/Mirosz/Desktop/project/test2/question.json: Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https

what i did wrong?!
How to load that file?!

Comment: This will help you why you got this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Comment: You need to use a local server for the request. `file` protocol doesn't allow ajax requests.

Comment: thanks all for help. can i ask for upvote?:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My crystal ball says that you are loading the model using either file:// or C:/, which stays true to the error message as they are not http://

So you can either install a webserver in your local PC or upload the model somewhere else and use jsonp and change the url to http://example.com/path/to/model

Answer (score 2):

Use a server to run your code, like [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) or [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

Answer (score 0):

Changing URL scheme to `http` resolves your problem.

The fast way I use sometime is, start a local development http server with python:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

and test on `http://localhost:8000/foo.html` instead of `file:///C:/.../foo.html`